# Google Tag Manager iframe

Tags: google-tag-manager

I'm working with some marketing folks and for one of the pages I have, they sent me some pixels to include on that page. They send me an iframe snippet from Mediaplex.

```
<iframe src="http://img-cdn.mediaplex.com/.....=" HEIGHT=1 WIDTH=1 FRAMEBORDER=0></iframe>
```

With Google Tag manager, I'm familiar with adding Custom HTML tags and Custom Image tags. However, how can I add that iframe snippet with Google Tag Manager?

Comment: In GTM, you can try using a Mediaplex tag type, found under Display Ad Tracking (there's Mediaplex - IFRAME MCT Tag, or Mediaplex - Standard IMG ROI Tag). I'm completely unfamiliar with Mediaplex, so wouldn't know how these work or how to implement them!

Comment: otherwise, a custom HTML tag should allow you to drop the iframe code on the site.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a Custom HTML Tag type. You'll want to configure your own Trigger for 'Some Pages' that fires when viewing the specific campaign page you need it for.

[image: Custom HTML Tag]

Answer (score 0):

Use this script inside a Custom HTML tag

```
<iframe src="http://img-cdn.mediaplex.com/....."
height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe>
```